# Python __str__ and __add__ output

Tags: python

I have the following example code, however, the output from `__add__` doesnt look the same as the `__str__` output. I need all output to look exactly like the `__str__` output format.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,x,y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return str(str(self.x/self.y) + "%")
    def __add__(self,other):
        if self.y > 50:
            return str((self.x + other.x)/(self.y+other.y)) + "%"
        else:
            return str((self.x + other.x)/(self.y+other.y)) + "%"
```

`__str__` output looks as such:

```
>>> a = Foo(1,3)
>>> print(a)
>>> 0.33333%
```

`__add__` output:

```
>>> Foo(1,3) + Foo(0,0)
>>> '0.33333%'
```

Why are there single quotes when I used `__add__` or `__sub__`  and not when I use `__str__`?

Comment: The difference is that first you `print` the result, and the second time your REPL just displays the result.

Comment: when you `print` a string, it doesn't print the quotes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be wise if `__add__` returned an instance of `Foo`? This way you could do `Foo(1,2)+Foo(3,4)+Foo(5,6)`.

Comment: Why do you want the add to return string?  Wouldn't you want Foo + Foo to = Foo?  You could then call `str` on the result.

Comment: I removed str() from add and also removed the "%", and the quote are gone, but now how do I add the percent back without getting an error?

Comment: It may be worth noting, that beyond the string format issues you're encountering, you're also adding your fractions incorrectly. `a/b + c/d` should be `(a*d+c*b)/(b*d)`.

Comment: Also `0` is a bit of a suicidal default value for a denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above: Your REPL shows quotes, when the result of the last operation is a string. Your REPL doesn't show quotes, when you print a string (and it supresses the resulting `None`).

As a minimal example of this behaviour, you can try this:

```
Python 3.2.4 (default, May 10 2013, 08:57:38) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 'Hello'
>>> a
'Hello'
>>> print(a)
Hello
```

Twice the same string, once displayed with, once without quotes.

---

Also consider returning an actual instance of Foo in your `__add__` method:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x / self.y) + "%"
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Foo(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

This way you can do e.g. `Foo(1, 2) + Foo(3, 4) + Foo(5, 6)` which you cannot with your code.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your custom `__add__` or even `__str__` methods - this is a feature of the interactive interpreter.

Usually, in a Python script, you'd need to use something like `print` to display output.

In the interactive however, interpreter there's a handy shortcut: You can enter any [**expression**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) and it will evaluate it, and print the *representation* of its result. This is often called a [read–eval–print loop (REPL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Notice the distinction above: It prints the **representation** of the result, not the result itself. This is usually (for primitive types and common objects) another Python expression that would recreate the same object.

So, in case of a string `a = 'foo'` the string is `foo`, but its representation is `'foo'`:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> print a
foo
>>> a
'foo'
```

To get the representation of an object, Python calls [`obj.__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (there's also a shorthand [`repr(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) which you can use).